# My game is not shown in Play Market New Releases

Tags: android, google-play

I've published my app for like an 36 hours ago. It is possible to find it with exact search query ("Village Keeper") and it is available via the direct [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ZinovyGames.VillageKeeper).

Thing is I can't find it in "New Releases" ("New Free Games") and I can't find it by typing something like "village game" or "keeper". So I have only 3 installs by me and my friends.

Is it a bug or is a new app not guaranteed to get in "New Releases"? I tried to google it but found no answers. If so, how can indie developer get into the market with no money for an ad campaign?

P. S. I tried to contact Google Support twice and 24 hours after first email passed with no reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be worried friend. Any store takes time to display your game in search queries. Second thing New Games or Apps are always featured one. And obviously getting featured is not an easy task. So it is very rare that your app/game is in that list at least at very beginning.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply! Can you mention some good ways to get first players with no money, please?

Comment: I think I should be very honest. And to be honest, the chance to getting there with no money is 0.01% with 100% luck. Getting my point?